# System.InvalidOperationException:An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework-6, excepciones

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en asp.net, web form, y necesito ayuda con esto:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple
instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

Esta excepción ocurre cuando trato de adicionar un elemento al `DbContext`.

Las entidades son `Usuario`, `Producto`, `ProductoDePedido`, `Pedido`.

```
 [Table("Productos")]
public class Producto
{
    public int ProductoId { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
} 

[Table("Pedidos")]
public class Pedido
{
    [Key]
    public int PedidoId{ get; set; }

    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductoDePedido> ProductosDePedido { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductosDePedidos")]
public class ProductoDePedido
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductoDePedidoId { get; set; }

    public int PedidoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }

    public int ProductoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando intento adicionar un nuevo pedido ocurre la excepcion,
este es el metodo donde lo adiciono:

```
public Pedido CrearPedido(Usuario usuario)
    {
        ProyectoDbContext context = new ProyectoDbContext();

        Pedido pedido = new Pedido
        {
            Usuario = usuario,
        };

        context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
    }
```

La cuestion es que no tengo idea del porque ocurre esta excepcion.
Tenia varias instancias del DBContext abiertas pero antes de llamar al
metodo, le hice .Dispose() a todas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `usuario` ha sido obtenido en un `DbContext` diferente al que se le está tratando de agregar.

Hay dos posibles soluciones:

La primera sería sacar el usuario del mismo `ProyectoDbContext`

```
public Pedido CrearPedido(Usuario usuario)
{
    using (var context = new ProyectoDbContext())
    {
        var usuarioExistente = context.Usuarios.Find(usuario.UsuarioId);

        var pedido = new Pedido
        {
            Usuario = usuarioExistente
        };

        context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
    }
}
```

La otra sería incluir solo el `IdUsuario` en el pedido, lo cual hará que se asocie al usuario correcto al momento de guardar los cambios.

```
public Pedido CrearPedido(Usuario usuario)
{
    using (var context = new ProyectoDbContext())
    {
        var pedido = new Pedido
        {
            UsuarioId = usuario.UsuarioId
        };

        context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Asi logre resolver el problema.